# Using dropdown menu and referencing query results

Tags: html, coldfusion, dropdown, cfselect

I am hoping this is an easy one I just don't know how to google the right answer.

I have a dropdown that is populated using a query.

```
<cfquery name="getFruits" datasource="#application.dsnName#" username="#application.dsnUser#" password="#application.dsnPass#">
SELECT TOP 3 fruit, color, size FROM fruit_table
</cfquery>

<cfselect name="fruits" query="getFruits" display="fruit" value="fruit" selected="#form.fruit#" queryPosition="below" required="yes" >
<option value="">Select Fruit</option>
</cfselect>
```

Is it possible when a user selects a 'fruit' from the dropdown to reference the 'size' and 'color' both associated with the 'fruit' they chose in another query?

For example:

```
<cfquery name="getFruits" datasource="#application.dsnName#" username="#application.dsnUser#" password="#application.dsnPass#">
SELECT vegetable FROM vegetable_table WHERE size = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" value="#form.size#"> AND color = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" value="#form.color#">
</cfquery>
```

Thanks!

Comment: This appears to be a simple form submission.  However, the fact that your fruits `cfselect` has a selected attribute seems odd.  Was there an earlier form submission to get to this fruits page?

Comment: @DanBracuk This would make sense if it was a self-posting form.

Comment: @DanBracuk That is from me just copying code. Submission of this form would reload the page and I wanted to display what was selected before using that attribute.

Comment: You can use a combination of ColdFusion and Javascript to change parts of a web page based on user input.  A google search of `coldfusion refresh div` will lead you to some code examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your form gets submitted, the value `form.fruits` gets posted without the `color` and `size` attributes.  So the way you would recode your `<cfquery>` (which I renamed to "getVegetables") to get those attributes from the selected fruit would be like this.

```
<cfquery name="getVegetables" datasource="#application.dsnName#" username="#application.dsnUser#" password="#application.dsnPass#">
    SELECT
        vegetable 
    FROM 
        vegetable_table 
    WHERE (size, color) IN
        (SELECT
            size, color 
        FROM 
            fruit_table
        WHERE
            fruit = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" value="#form.fruits#">)
</cfquery>
```

BTW, I'm not a fan of using `<cfselect>` or any `<cfform>` tags, but that wasn't your question.  However, I would highly suggest discarding it and refactoring your code.

**EDIT (second attempt):**

As an alternate answer, if you want to pass the `size,color` columns concatenated with a comma and aliased as `sizeColor` from the form instead of the the `fruit` column from your `<cfquery>`, then what you can do instead is change the first select statement to

```
<cfquery name="getFruits" datasource="#application.dsnName#" username="#application.dsnUser#" password="#application.dsnPass#">
SELECT TOP 3 
fruit,
size || ',' || color AS sizeColor 
FROM fruit_table
</cfquery>
```

then change the value attribute to `value="sizeColor"` in your `<cfselect>` which will be the aforementioned comma delimited list of the size and color.  So the code would instead be

```
<cfselect name="fruits" query="getFruits" display="fruit" value="sizeColor" selected="#form.fruit#" queryPosition="below" required="yes" >
<option value="">Select Fruit</option>
</cfselect>
```

Then you can change the `<cfquery>` on the posted page to this.

```
<cfquery name="getVegetables" datasource="#application.dsnName#" username="#application.dsnUser#" password="#application.dsnPass#">
SELECT vegetable FROM vegetable_table 
WHERE 
    size = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" value="#form.fruits.listGetAt(1)#"> AND 
    color = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" maxlength="50" value="#form.fruits.listGetAt(2)#">
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I envisioned but didn't know how to implement. I am attempting this now but running into an error. When I use the comma delimited value I get an error "Query column invalid or missing..." even though these are two valid columns from the cfquery and work fine if used individually. Any advice?

Comment: Ah, this comes from my lack of experience with `<cfselect>` which doesn't allow variable names in the `value` field but a string literal of a specific column from your SQL select statement.  What you can do instead is create a computed column of size, comma, color concatenated and aliased and use the aliased column e.g. `size || ',' || color sizeColor` (presuming double pipe is your concatenation operator) and use `sizeColor` as your `value` attribute.  I'll modify my answer.

Comment: You are a wise man user1203119, thanks again for your assistance.